# how to install apache ANT manually?

Tags: apache, ant

i try to install apache ANT but when i run my CMD they give me this message..

> **'ant-version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file..**

can anyone help me with this..

Answer (score 2):

Installing Ant is fairly simple to do manually:

1. Find the directory where you want to install Ant.
2. Unzip it.
3. Setup `ANT_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.
4. Put `$ANT_HOME/bin` (`%ANT_HOME\bin`) in your `PATH`.

And, that's about it. I like to *link* my executables to `/usr/local/bin` rather than adding more and more directories into my `PATH`.

Maybe your problem is this: `ant-version` is not a command. Maybe you meant `ant -version`? Note the space.

Comment: i already follow all the manual installation step..but the cmd give me the same message..

Comment: Try `which ant`, see if it returns the path of your Ant binary.

Comment: Are you typing `ant -version` as TWO words? Your OP says you typed in both run together. The command is `ant`, and the parameter is `-version`. You need a space between them.